# How can I implement a class when one of its properties is an enum variable?

Tags: java, oop, enums

I want to create `Node` objects with `state` properties. `state` property can be determined as one of three enum variables: `enum State = {visited, unvisited, visiting};`

So, for example, I would like to do `Node n1; n1.state = State.unvisited;` In this case, `n1` is a Node object in a `Graph` object. In order to do this, I need to create a `Node` class. What should the type of `state` property be?

```
class Node {
    [type] state;
    public Node() {
        // say something about the state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `enum` as follows:

```
enum State {
  Visited,
  Unvisited,
  Visiting    
}
```

Once that is done, you can define your property as follows:

```
State state;
```

Comment: Thank you @Sujeet Sinha. Should I create `State` as a class too?

Comment: No, once you create the `enum`, you can use the same name as the type of the property. The `enum` should be defined outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

> What should the type of state property be?

`State`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the enum outside the class and then make instance of that enum inside the class as follows.

```
enum State {
  Visited,
  Unvisited,
  Visiting    
}
class Node {
    State state;
    public Node() {
        // say something about the state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Enum data type :

```
public enum State {
  VISITED,
  UNVISITED,
  VISITING    
}
```

Then your class should look something like this:

```
class Node {
    State state;
    public Node() {
        // say something about the state
    }
}
```

An instance of your class would look like this :

```
Node node1, node2;
node1 = new Node();
node2 = new Node();
node1.state = State.VISITED;
node2.state = State.UNVISITED;
```

For more reading check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-in-java/), or Google about `enumerations`, you will find more information.

Answer (score 0):

That would look something like this:
(I've changed the names to Upper-Case, as that's the convention for enums)

To refer to them you'd code `State.VISITED` with `import packagename.State;`
or just `UNVISITED` with `import static packagename.State.*;`

```
public class Enum60963806 {

    public static enum State {
          VISITED,
        UNVISITED,
          VISITING;
    }
    public static final class Node {

        private final State state;

        public Node(final State state) {
            this.state = state;
        }
    }
}
```